# Network Programming in C for name of running process for established connection

Tags: c, network-programming, conky

I am new to C network programming. I am trying to code a patch for my conky to display something like "netstat -pan --inet". Conky's inbuilt tcp_mon to not include process name.

Initially I did this using netstat and awk but my script got a performance hit using this approach. So I am trying to code it in C directly. The output from netstat looks something like this

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State           PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:17500           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN         1042/dropbox        
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.1:3333        24.244.4.104:2222     ESTABLISHED    1225/chrome
```

I am interested in displaying the last column "PID/Program" I look at the sockets library but I did not come across anything regarding the process name or its pid. I am on Archlinux by the way

So my questions are
1) Am I looking at the right place ? If not, where ?
2) Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: What exactly to expect to be a process' name?

Comment: The program that established the network connection. I edited the post to reflect this. Thank you.

Comment: After digging through netstat source, 
I found all I need is in `/proc/net/*`
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least when using a recent Linux kernel it is possible to read out a process' name (as defined by a comment to the OP) using `prctl()`:

```
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <stdio.h> /* for perror() */
...

char [17] = proc_name = {0}; /* the buffer provided shall at least be 16+1 bytes long */

if (-1 == prctl(PR_GET_NAME, proc_name, ...))
  perror("prctl(PR_GET_NAME, ...)");
```

One should be aware that a maximum of 16 bytes is returned, and that in this case **no** trailing `0`-termination will be added. So initialising the character array to passed to `prctl()`to all `0` is a good idea.

It is also possible to set this "name" by doing:

```
char [17] = proc_name = "new name"; /* The name will be truncated to 16 bytes */

if (-1 == prctl(PR_SET_NAME, proc_name, ...))
  perror("prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ...)");
```

The relevant excerpts from `prctl()`'s man pages are:

> **PR_SET_NAME** (since Linux 2.6.9)
>
> Set the process name for the calling process, using the value in the location pointed to by (char *) arg2.  The name can be up to 16 bytes long, and should be null-terminated if it contains fewer bytes.
>
> **PR_GET_NAME** (since Linux 2.6.11)
>
> Return the process name for the calling process, in the buffer pointed to by (char *) arg2.  The buffer should allow space for up to 16 bytes; the returned string will be null-terminated if it is shorter than that.

---

Please note that the "process name"-value as described above is different form the command line for a process. The latter can be found in `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`.

It is stored in there as `0`-terminated character array.

---

A convenient way to read out `/proc` is to use the [tool kit provided by PROCPS](http://procps.sourceforge.net/).

---

**Update**:

After taking a look at `netstat`'s sources it seem it takes the process's name from `/proc/<pid>/cmdline`. The relevant pids come from scanning `/proc/<pid>/fd` looking for matches to `socket:*`.

Comment: I guess I shall try out netstat's method as indicated in its sources using PROCPS tools or just code it up myself. Since /proc reside in ram, I think it should be alright. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

assuming Linux, I think you've got to go into /proc/*/fd and poke around

Comment: Hi , thanks for the advice. There are indeed information regarding this. Is it possible to do it in c code via the libraries without accessing any files on the system. I am hoping to achieved the a reasonable good performance. Thanks again !

Comment: You are asking for information that belongs to the OS Kernel, and that there isn't really a properly standardized method of introspecting. There's no syscall, as far as I know, to request the PID of a socket, port, or listener. However, on Linux (and some other operating systems) the kernel makes various pieces of internal information (such as the process table) available by representing the data as a virtual file system under the `/proc` directory. If you want this information, you need to access it the way the kernel presents it. (Alternatively, you could look into the `lsof` tool.)